# Azure DevOps REST API, retrieve current environment status

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

We have a small development/testing environment setup on Azure VMs that only run during business hours. Sometimes one of our Devs may complete a PR after hours. This generally results in a failed build/deployment as the Azure VMs are shutdown.

For a different project that utilises the Classic Release and Deployment Groups, I have a PowerShell script that checks the Azure VMs and starts them if they're shutdown. (this is done via the [DeploymentGroups API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups)

I'm currently setting up some new pipelines using YAML where the deployments utilise environments for approvals, etc... These new pipelines are running without any problems and provide a clearer picture of our overall build/release process.

One thing I haven't been able to determine is how to check the status of the Environment prior to commencing a deployment job. The [Environment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) documentation doesn't show any status items. And of course I don't see anything in the returned object.

Open to options on how to check the status, then subsequently start and stop the VMs as required during the deployment process.

Comment: Maybe try pinging the VMs to see if they are online?